# How to set origin of object to the lowest point

Tags: objects, object-mode

The origin of my object is at the middle, and I want it at the bottom. My model is not located at the right location for setting it to world origin to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Preferences( <kbd>F4</kbd>  ->  <kbd>P</kbd> ), Add-ons tab and search for 3D Viewport Pie Menus add-on that comes with Blender, once you enable it and get more options, you can disable the ones you don't need(they might interfare with the way you are used to hotkeys to work), but make sure you have Origin Pie enabled:

[image]

Once you have that  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>X</kbd>  hotkey will call the menu

[image]

Origin to Bottom does what you need.

You can also use native functionality of simply moving the origin point if you enable Affect Only: Origins:

[image]

With that enabled you can use all regular transform operators:  <kbd>G</kbd> ,  <kbd>R</kbd> ,  <kbd>S</kbd>  to transform the origin any way you want and you can also use snap functionality.

Answer (score 1):

2 separate problems.
First, in edit mode, select lowest part of mesh and pick cursor to selection. Then in object mode select origin to 3d cursor.
Next, shift C to put cursor to world origin. Then select your mesh and pick object to 3d cursor. Your mesh should now be at center of world.